# Not able to replace sub string having bracket from string array in typescript/javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I have a string 
e.g. My column name is Start Date (GMT)

I want to replace Start Date (GMT) portion with start_date.

I am trying to do it like:

```
    let a= "My column name is Start Date (GMT)";
    let b = "Start Date (GMT)";
    let str = new RegExp(b,"g");
    console.log(a.replace(str,"start_date"));
```

With same code I am able to replace the string with desired value if brackets are not there, but since bracket '(' is there it is not able to identify the string and replace it.

Comment: So, as always, just escape the literal pattern string, `let str = new RegExp(b.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'),"g");`

Answer (score 0):

This would work.

`while` loop will run till all the `Start Date (GMT)` are replaced by `start_date`.

```js
let str = "My column name is Start Date (GMT) Start Date (GMT)";

while(str != str.replace('Start Date (GMT)', 'start_date')) {
  str = str.replace('Start Date (GMT)', 'start_date');
}

console.log(str);
```

Comment: I doubt OP wants to use a string replace, the `g` modifier hints at the OP intention to replace multiple occurrences.

Comment: Actually i want it for multiple occurrence only. Above code snippet was just example.

Comment: I have updated the code